# (function() { document.getElementById() == null; })();

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, self-executing-function

Why self-executing anonymous function can't get access to DOM elements. Why such example does not work.

```
(function() {
    alert(document.getElementById('someElement'));
)();
```

Why alert will show "null"?

Comment: The function has nothing to do with it. The `getElemenById` call would return the same thing inside or outside of the function.

Comment: Show the html and the order of your code.

Comment: that's is my question, actually. Isn't that function supposed to be  executed after DOM loaded?

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing that with `$(function()`.

Comment: here is that example: http://jsfiddle.net/4mue2u5e/

Comment: Andy, it's pure js, i don't use jquery

Comment: @MarkZucchini: Exactly, hence you are confusing an IIFE with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute it on DOM load.You can use script defer attribute also.

```
(function() {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        alert(document.getElementById('someElement'));
    }, false);
})();
```

Comment: maybe that's the way. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your missing your closing curly brace `}`.

It should be

```
(function() {
    alert(document.getElementById('someElement'));
})();
```

**This will execute immediately so this needs to be placed somewhere appropriate to ensure the DOM has loaded**. Make sure this script loads at the end of your HTML file, or include a check as Georgi Naumov has suggested, adding a listener to the window.load event will do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I thought that this function executes after DOM loaded, not immediatelly